# Existence of primes Of a given form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

---

Given a prime $p$ and an integer $n \neq 1$, not divisible by $p$, does there always exists a prime, or possibly infinitude of primes $q$ such that $p+nq$ is also prime? Same questions when $P$ is an irreducible polynomial, $N$ is a polynomial which does not divide $p$, and we want a prime number $q$ such that $P(x)+qN(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: We are given both $p$ and $n$, it is not true in general that for any given $p$ and $n$ $p+2n$ would be prime, isn't it?

Comment: Of course not, sorry I misread the "Variable" to be $n$ and not $q$.

Comment: Well, for variable $n$ this reduces to well known Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Note: Dirichlet's Theorem cited by Stef does not count as elementary number theory.

Comment: @Stef Counterexample for the "infinitude": $p=3$, $n=1$. The only valid $q$ is $2$ yielding $\{5\}$, an obviously finite set.

Comment: Indeed, for $p=2$ and $n=1$ the infinitude is just the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: My guess is that this question is too general that it will not have a simple answer. As Dietrich Burde noted, this problem is very similar to the twin prime conjecture and variants and is likely to be very hard. Did you invent this yourself or have you found it somewhere?

Comment: So for p=13 and n=1 this istotally impossible, maybe n=1 case must be omitted.

Comment: This is just a hypothesis, it seems unlikely that all numbers of form $p+nq$ would turn out to be composite. My first conjecture was about polynomials with $N=x^k$ for $k \geq deg P + 1, but I have no idea if that is true.

Comment: negative $n$ does not change the situation, if we treat both $p$ and $-p$ as primes.

Answer (score 1):

For odd $p$ and odd $n$ there need not exist any prime $q$ such that $p+nq$ is prime. Take $p=19$ and $n=3$. Suppose that $p+nq=19+3q$ is prime. This is always even, except for $q=2$, where we have $p+nq=25$.